# Creating a work hours component - How to useState with multiple values going into an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

To clarify my question - I'm build a component that will set the work hours for a worker during the week. I don't need the work day as I'm just gonna use the index of the array for the work day (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday.. etc). So currently the workingDaysOfWeek is just to display them. There will be 2 textfields to enter in a start time and an end time. I need to figure out how to add these times to an array.. which eventually will be added to one big array that will determine which work day those hours correspond too. So in short. I need an array that holds 2 values.. a start and end time. The 0 index should be the start and 1 index should be the end. Here is kind of the schema I'm looking for and also the component

The current code below will keep giving undefines when I change the text fields... I tried using `unshift` and `push` however this only worked for one of them and not the other. I'm not use how to add these times seperately into the array or if using `useState` is the best idea.

```
{
  "working_hours": [
    ["09:00:00Z-07:00:00", "17:00:00Z-07:00:00"], // Monday
    ["09:00:00Z-07:00:00", "17:00:00Z-07:00:00"],
    ["09:00:00Z-07:00:00", "17:00:00Z-07:00:00"],
    ["09:00:00Z-07:00:00", "17:00:00Z-07:00:00"],
    ["09:00:00Z-07:00:00", "15:00:00Z-07:00:00"],
    null, // Saturday
    null // Sunday
  ]
}
```

WorkingDays

```
const WorkingDays = () => {
  const workingDaysOfWeek = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday'
  ]
  const [workingDaysHours, setWorkingDaysHours] = useState([])

  function handleStartChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setWorkingDaysHours(e.target.value)
    console.log(workingDaysHours)
  };

  function handleEndChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setWorkingDaysHours(e.target.value)
    console.log(workingDaysHours)
  }

  return (
    <form noValidate>
        {
          workingDaysOfWeek.map((days,index) => (
            <Grid container direction={'row'}>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
              <Typography >
                {days}
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={2}>
          <TextField
          id={index}
          label="Start Time"
          type="time"
          onChange={handleStartChange}
          InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
          inputProps={{
          step: 300, // 5 min
        }}
          />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4}>
          <TextField
          id="end_time"
          label="End Time"
          type="time"
          onChange={handleEndChange}
          InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
          inputProps={{
          step: 300, // 5 min
        }}
          />
          </Grid>
            </Grid>
          ))
        }
    </form>
  )
}

export default WorkingDays
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are setting a value for a day over the entire array. You are calling `setWorkingDaysHours` with a single value and it replaces your whole array.
It might work better if your update functions were

```
function handleStartChange(day, hours) {
    const newArray = [...workingDaysHours];
    newArray[day][0] = hours;
    setWorkingDaysHours(newArray);
}
function handleEndChange(day, hours) {
    const newArray = [...workingDaysHours];
    newArray[day][1] = hours;
    setWorkingDaysHours(newArray);
}
```

Then your callback should be called like

```
// Day being the variable taken from the map method
onChange={ev => handleStartChange(day, ev.target.value)}
```